# require js jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Do I have to write wrappers for each jQuery plugin I am trying to use in require.js? I can't user the order plugin they still give me the error that they depend on jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain more? Examples of the plugins you're trying to use and how you're combining them would be useful. It's worth noting that all jQuery plugins will obviously require a jQuery include somewhere on the same page, if that's the problem you're having.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RequireJS 2.0 has a `shim` option that allows you to use older non-AMD scripts as modules - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [How to use require js with jquery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)?  It explains that you can use require js to load jquery and jquery plugins by using a combined jquery/requirejs file.  You can find a sample project [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#samplejquery).  There are also several alternative strategies listed in the sample project's [readme](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery).